# Is there a way to mark complete after manual shipping?

Tags: shipping, status

We have received orders in magento and shipped them manually. The problem is that magento wasn't consulted about the shipping and is now preventing us from setting the order status as complete. What is the best way to solve this problem?

magento 1.9 CE
I know this has already been addressed, im just looking for the best way besides canceling transactions or simply leaving them as processing or pending.

Answer (score 1):

In short, if there is a paid invoice, and all items are shipped, then the order is already complete. If this is a core bug (not to my knowledge) then **you should upgrade** to fix the issue. There may already be a SUPEE patch available for your particular issue, as well.

If your *business rules* call an order complete outside of these requirements you'll have to do some fancy footwork. In general creating a module to move to complete is one way, whether automatically or via a button, but I've also seen people create statuses in Complete state that allow them to modify the state of an already completed order on the fly by adding an Admin comment.

Best of luck.

Comment: So basically if I don't hit the ship button but instead get on the phone and call a courier, the order can never be marked as shipped even though the customer has the products?